# lightdm package upgrade fails with exit status 30

Tags: dpkg

Running an upgrade on my Ubuntu 15.10 box recently failed when updating `lightdm`. Here's what I get when I try reconfigure and force install again:

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure --force lightdm 

$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up lightdm (1.16.7-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing package lightdm (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 30
Errors were encountered while processing:
 lightdm
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

However, upon looking at the package status, here's what I get:

```
$ dpkg --status lightdm
Package: lightdm
Status: install ok half-configured
Priority: optional
Section: x11
Installed-Size: 612
Maintainer: Robert Ancell <robert.ancell@ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 1.16.7-0ubuntu1
Config-Version: 1.16.6-0ubuntu1
Provides: x-display-manager
Depends: debconf (>= 0.5) | debconf-2.0, lsb-base (>= 4.1+Debian11ubuntu7), libc6 (>= 2.14), libgcrypt20 (>= 1.6.0), libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.37.3), libpam0g (>= 0.99.7.1), libxcb1, libxdmcp6, libpam-runtime (>= 0.76-14), libpam-modules, adduser, libglib2.0-bin, dbus, plymouth (>= 0.8.8-0ubuntu18), bash (>= 4.3)
Pre-Depends: dpkg (>= 1.15.7.2)
Recommends: xserver-xorg, unity-greeter | lightdm-greeter | lightdm-kde-greeter
Conflicts: liblightdm-gobject-0-0, liblightdm-qt-0-0
Conffiles:
 /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/lightdm cb9275330661d269fe38e04008e153de
 /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/lightdm_chromium-browser c378a6d8a20e213abc15909e72567203
 /etc/apparmor.d/lightdm-guest-session 7d122d506d65910f9252b5b36aeb13a1
 /etc/dbus-1/system.d/org.freedesktop.DisplayManager.conf b76b6b45d7f7ff533c51d7fc02be32f4
 /etc/init.d/lightdm be2b1b20bec52a04c1a877477864e188
 /etc/init/lightdm.conf 07304e5b3265b4fb82a2c94beb9b577e
 /etc/lightdm/users.conf 1de1a7e321b98e5d472aa818893a2a3e
 /etc/pam.d/lightdm 1abe2be7a999b42517c82511d9e9ba22
 /etc/pam.d/lightdm-autologin 28dd060554d1103ff847866658431ecf
 /etc/pam.d/lightdm-greeter 65ed119ce8f4079f6388b09ad9d8b2f9
Description: Display Manager
 LightDM is a X display manager that:
  * Has a lightweight codebase
  * Is standards compliant (PAM, ConsoleKit, etc)
  * Has a well defined interface between the server and user interface
  * Cross-desktop (greeters can be written in any toolkit)
Homepage: https://launchpad.net/lightdm
```

Could someone help figure out how to fix this package?

Comment: What's the output of `sudo apt-get install -f --reinstall lightdm`?

Comment: I get the following:
`0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
E: Internal Error, No file name for lightdm:amd64`

Comment: Potentially related: [1](/q/266450/175814), [2](/q/167784/175814). If cleaning up the local repository information as suggested in these questions doesn't help, what happens when you run `apt-get download lightdm && sudo dpkg -i lightdm_*.deb`?

Comment: Strange, I get this error when trying to download : `E: Unable to locate package ligthdm`

Comment: It's `lightdm`, not `ligthdm`.

Comment: Sorry, I corrected that. The download succeeded but installation fails again with the same message: `dpkg: error processing package lightdm (--install):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 30`

Comment: I have one more idea: purge and re-install (`sudo dpkg --purge --force-depends lightdm && sudo apt-get install lightdm`). Otherwise you should [report this as a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm).

Answer (score 0):

[Print Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8ct4.png)

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unattended-upgrades
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

For your problem:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall lightdm
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Comment: Running a reinstall returns a: `E: Internal Error, No file name for lightdm:amd64`